# Кликабельная ссылка (forward) на конкретное сообщение телеграма

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Работаю над телеграм ботом для струтурирования информации из группового чата: нужно, чтобы бот возвращал список кликабельных ссылок (форвардов) на конкретные сообщения из группового чата

Проблема, что не понятно, как сделать клюкабельную ссылку на сообщение.

Пробовал 2 подхода:

1. Используя метод aiogram `await bot.forward_message(...)`

```
await bot.forward_message(chat_id=bot_chat_id, from_chat_id=group_chat_id, message_id=250)
```

Получается просто цитирование целевого сообщения, цитата не кликабельна

2. Вернуть сообщение со ссылкой в html формате

```
await bot.send_message(chat_id=bot_chat_id, text="<a href='https://t.me/{group_chat_id}/250'>message URL</a>", parse_mode='HTML')
```

Ссылка не рабочая, внятной инструкции как собрать вручную ссылку не нашел.

Кстати, если даже вручную форварднуть сообщение в личном чате - ссылка не кликабельна. Только *Reply* создает кликательную ссылку.

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

кажется, что был какой-то временный баг в ТГ
ссылка типа
`https://t.me/c/{target_chat_id}/{message_id}` работает

Answer (score 0):

В первом методе chat_id - id пользователя которому шлешь, переменная group_chat_id должна иметь вид '@что-то' иначе не сработает